# Centering a responsive slideshow

Tags: css, slideshow, responsive-design, centering

I'm using the RefineSlide responsive slideshow and I can't center it, it always sticks to the left of my page.

```
#slideshow{
position: relative;
width: 960px;
height:auto;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -480px;
}
```

I've tried adding the above to my CSS, and although this successfully centers it, it's unfortunately no longer responsive as when I test on the iPhone the slideshow doesn't fit to the screen.

```
#slideshow{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height:auto;
}
```

When I style it like this, it is responsive... but sticks to the left. What do I need to change with this CSS to center it and keep it responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It somewhat depends on your other markup, but in general this is enough:

```
#slideshow {
    margin: auto;
    width: Npx;
    /* also display: block if the element doesn't already have it */
}
```

[**Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/xUzYt/).

Comment: This does center it, but it's not responsive. It seems whenever I change the width from percentage into pixels it stops it from being responsive.

Comment: @user1636968: By itself that [would make no difference](http://jsfiddle.net/xUzYt/) -- the rest of your markup plays a role here.